# Python оптимальный алгоритм для шифрования

Tags: python, алгоритм, шифрование

Имеется задача. Во время шифрования алгоритм принимает символы шифруемого текста по одному и заменяет этот символ на один другой символ. Кодировка состоит из m символов, поэтому можно считать, что текст представляет собой последовательность натуральных чисел, не превосходящих. Во время работы алгоритм шифрования поддерживает перестановку натуральных чисел от 1 до m. В начале работы перестановка тождественна. Когда алгоритму на вход поступает символ x, алгоритм заменяет его на номер позиции в перестановке (в 1-индексации), на которой находится символ x, а также переносит x в начало перестановки. Например, если в некоторый момент работы алгоритма перестановка символов в нём равна [3, 1, 2], а на вход подаётся символ 1, то символ 1 будет заменён на символ 2, поскольку 1 стоит в перестановке на второй позиции, а перестановка примет вид [1, 3, 2].

Я написал код:

```
def encrypt(disp):
    res = []
    for i in input().split():
        pos = disp.index(int(i))
        res.append(pos + 1)
        disp = [disp[pos]] + disp[:pos] + disp[pos + 1:]
    return res
```

На вход поступает начальное состояние перестановки. Например [1, 2, 3, 4]. Пример работы алгоритма:
2 1 2 3 1 3 1 -> 2 2 2 3 3 2 2.
Проблема в том, что мой алгоритм не укладывается в отведенный лимит времени. Может, есть способы ускорить работу? 
Работа алгоритма станет понятней если его показать таблицей. Зашифруем слово 2 3 1 2 1 1 1. Пусть x - входная буква, p - состояние перестановки на момент вхождения, y - результат.

[image: c[]

Comment: После неоднократного чтения условия понятнее не стало. Так и в задаче сформулировано?

Comment: @rokitoker Добавил схему работы алгоритма

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как минимум.

input().split() вынести за цикл, после ввода определять количество введенных знаков, порождать res сразу нужного размера а потом работать с ним не как с списком динамически изменяемого размера, а как с массивом.

Comment: Это незначительно ускорит работу

Comment: @exeynod значит вы не очень понимаете, на сколько ресурсоемкая процедура добавления элемента в динамический список и на сколько операции над массивами быстрее операций со списками.

Comment: что вы понимаете под статическим массивом в python тогда? Numpy использовать нельзя